# How to setup eosiocpp to find standard libraries?

Tags: development

I pulled the eos github repo and compiled the tools.

Now, in my project folder, I want to compile the contract like

```
~/repo/eosio/eos/build/tools/eosiocpp -o contract/contract.wast contract/contract.cpp
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
contract/contract.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 
      'eosiolib/eosio.hpp' file not found
       #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to fix: fatal error: 'eosiolib/eosio.hpp' file not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the build script in the eos folder (`./eosio_build.sh`) it is required to install the executables as mentioned [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment#install-the-executables) using

```
sudo make install
```

in the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Incase your are using docker setup. 

For me I have changed the relative path to absolute path

```
#include </home/<pc_name>/pathToContractFolder/contracts/eosio.contracts/eosio.token/include/eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp>
```